# How to make Gradle stop trying to chmod MANIFEST.MF on an NTFS drive

Tags: linux, gradle, file-permissions, ntfs

I'm somewhat new at Gradle. My development PC dual-boots both Windows and Linux, and so I have an NTFS "data drive" that both OS's share, and I keep all of my development files on this drive. I have a Gradle Java project that compiles fine under Windows, but, under Linux, it fails with this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to '/(...my project path...)/build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF'.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to '/(...my project path...)/build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.MapFileTree$FileVisitDetailsImpl.getFile(MapFileTree.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$1.visitFile(AbstractFileTree.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$FilteredFileTree$1.visitFile(AbstractFileTree.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.MapFileTree$Visit.visit(MapFileTree.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.MapFileTree.visit(MapFileTree.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:96)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$FilteredFileTree.visit(AbstractFileTree.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree.getFiles(AbstractFileTree.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getFiles(CompositeFileCollection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSnapshotter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.InputFilesStateChangeRule.create(InputFilesStateChangeRule.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init>(TaskUpToDateState.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ContextualisingTaskExecuter.execute(ContextualisingTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:282)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:27)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to set file permissions 420 on file MANIFEST.MF. errno: 1
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.filesystem.LibcChmod.chmod(LibcChmod.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.filesystem.GenericFileSystem.chmod(GenericFileSystem.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:67)
    ... 77 more
```

Googling this error turned up absolutely nothing. Of course, the reason for the error is clear enough: NTFS doesn't support UNIX file permissions (well, it technically *can*, but I don't have it configured that way because it messes with Windows's permissions). When I copied the project to my Linux partition and tried the compile again, it worked.

I looked through the Gradle docs, and can't seem to find any way to tell it not to set permissions on MANIFEST.MF. (Why does it even need to do that in the first place?) Of course, Gradle has a *lot* of options, so there may just be something I'm overlooking. Is there any way to tell it to stop trying to set permissions?

Comment: A stack trace (`--full-stacktrace`) might help to clarify who is responsible for this.

Comment: Ok, it's been edited. My goal isn't to find out what's causing it, though; it's to find out how to turn off Gradle's chmod "feature".

Comment: The stack trace will help to answer the question if there is a way to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is trying to set default permissions for that file, and I can't see a way to stop it from doing that. (You could make it set different permissions, but I guess that won't help.) Under Windows/NTFS this normally works just fine, so it might be a problem with you Linux NTFS driver or configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to modify your mount options, the filesystem type of `fat` has the `quiet` option.  This option causes chmod/chown operations to fail silently, so Gradle thinks they succeed when they actually do nothing.

This works for `fat` and `vfat` (which inherits the `quiet` option) mounts, but I am not sure if `ntfs` mounts also inherit this option.